# Selected Date Field wont stay on page after clicking out of field

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-web-components, lightning

I've just created my first visualforce page and having an issue with the opportunity close date. When I select the close date on the page, I am able to enter this via typing it out or the date picker. The issue I'm running into now is that the selected date wont stay in the field after I click out of the field.

For example, I enter 9-27-2022, when I click out of the field, it reverts back to having no input.

Do I need to create a separate class for this field?

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" lightningStylesheets="TRUE" showHeader="TRUE" docType="html-5.0">
<apex:SectionHeader title="New Opportunity"> 
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Add Opportunity"  mode="edit">
        
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Name}"  required="TRUE"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.AccountId}"  required="TRUE" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Stagename}"  required="TRUE"  /> 
                <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Type}"  required="TRUE"  /> 
                <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Starting_ARR__c}"  required="TRUE" /> 
                <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Product__c}"  required="TRUE" /> 
                <apex:inputField type="date" showDatePicker="TRUE" value="{!Opportunity.CloseDate}" required="TRUE" /> 
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:form >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Additional Information"  mode="edit">
                <apex:pageBlockButtons location = "bottom" >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel" immediate="true"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons> 
         <apex:pageBlockSection >
            <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Competitor__c }" /> 
              <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Other_Competitor__c }" /> 
               <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Product_Gap__c}"  required="TRUE"  /> 
         </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>            
    </apex:form>
</apex:SectionHeader>
```

</apex:page>

Answer (score 1):

Set

> showDatePicker = "false"

should work. Setting showDatePicker = "true" is defaulting the date format to dd/mm/yyyy format which doesn't conform to HTML5